# withCount alongside recursive query Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to retrieve the number of replies a comment has with Eloquent using `withCount()`. So far I have defined the following relationships:

*QuoteComments*

```
protected $withCount = [
        'replies'
    ];

public function replies(){
    return $this->hasMany(QuotesComments::class, 'reply_id');
}
```

Using the `withCount()`

```
$quoteComments = QuotesComments::where('quote_id', $quoteid)
            ->whereNull('reply_id') // We don't want to show comments that are reply to other comments
            ->orderBy('votes', 'DESC')
            ->withCount('replies');
```

Database scheme:

```
id   quote_id   reply_id 
1    2          NULL
2    2          1
```

I'm getting the error `Maximum function nesting level of '512' reached, aborting!` which I'm guessing may be because of the recursive calls that `withCount()` may be doing. Any light at the end of the tunnel would be great. Thank you in advance

Comment: What exactly is the issue?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir I edited the question to say what the problem was. In case its easier the problem is that I get the following error: `Maximum function nesting level of '512' reached, aborting!`. Any solution to the problem?

Comment: I don't think you can use `$withCount` in this case. Do you really need it? In the query you posted,  `->withCount('replies')` achieves the expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be honest it was such a silly mistake from my part. I was checking documentation from older versions of Laravel and mixing with the newest (5.7).

What happened was that in my model I was inserting:

```
protected $withCount = [
        'replies'
    ];
```

when in fact it wasn't necessary. I just had to call the function `withCount()` in the Controller with the final result being only:

```
$quoteComments = QuotesComments::where('quote_id', $quoteid)
            ->whereNull('reply_id') // We don't want to show comments that are reply to other comments
            ->orderBy('votes', 'DESC')
            ->withCount('replies');
```

Answer (score 0):

change  `->withCount('replies');` to `->with('replies')->count();`

EDIT

*if You Want to count data with not null reply_id*

change
  `->withCount('replies');` 
to

```
->with(['replies'=>function($query){$query->where('reply_id','!=','NULL')->get();}])->count();
```

Comment: This will return the total number of `QuotesComments` which is not the objective. The objective is to get the total number of replies to that specific comment

Comment: aha  try ->with(['replies'=>function($query){$query->where('reply_id','!=','NULL')->get();}])->count();

Answer (score 0):

use whereHas in your query to not consider comment who don't have replies. It will return only those comment who has at-least one replay.

```
$quoteComments = QuotesComments::where('quote_id', $quoteid)
         ->whereHas('replies')
        ->whereNull('reply_id') // We don't want to show comments that are reply to other comments
        ->orderBy('votes', 'DESC')
        ->withCount('replies');
```